# How to test a component that receives a ref as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I want to snapshot a component in React using `react-test-renderer`. The component I want to test receives a `ref` from another component. The component I'm testing relies on a function implemented by the component which is passing the ref as props:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, Paper, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { INodeInfoProps } from "./interfaces";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    padding: 10,
    maxHeight: 600,
    width: 400,
    overflowWrap: "break-word",
    "& p": {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
  },
  channels: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  channelsComponent: {
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
});

export const NodeInfo: React.FC<INodeInfoProps> = ({ graphRef, info }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const getDivCoords = () => {
    if (graphRef.current) {
      const nodeCoordinates = graphRef.current.graph2ScreenCoords(
        info?.x || 0,
        info?.y || 0,
        info?.z || 0
      );

      return {
        top: nodeCoordinates.y + 20,
        left: nodeCoordinates.x,
      };
    }
    return { top: 0, left: 0 };
  };

  if (info && graphRef.current) {
    return (
      <Paper
        className={classes.container}
        style={{
          top: getDivCoords().top,
          left: getDivCoords().left,
        }}
      >
        <Typography>Pubkey: {info.publicKey}</Typography>
        <Typography>Alias: {info.alias}</Typography>
      </Paper>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

So the function `graph2ScreenCoords` is implemented in the component which the ref is received by props by my component.

My test component would look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import {NodeInfo} from "../index";

it('should render each node info', () => {
    const info = {
        publicKey: "test123",
        alias: "test",
        color: "#fff",
        visible: true,
        links: [
            {
                channelId: "123",
                node1: "test123",
                node2: "test345",
                capacity: "10000",
                color: "#fff"
            }
        ]
    }
    const tree = renderer.create(<NodeInfo graphRef={} info={info}/>).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

But I need to pass the ref to the test component, so it can access the function `graph2ScreenCoords`.

How should I make it the right way? Should I render the component in my test, create a ref and pass it as props? Should I mock the ref? How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck with this? Most answers say to 'just mock useRef', which IMO is a stupid solution

Comment: Yeah, mock the `useRef` and what is being passed should be the correct answer

Comment: and for a component that has custom ref functions? like myComponentRef.current.close() and myComponentRef.current.open() - this approach won't work

Comment: You can also mock those functions. You should mock whatever useRef is implementing